# Change query string via location bar, AJAX loaded menu doesn't repopulate without hard refresh

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom

I have a UL populated via an AJAX call that gets it's contents based on an ID in the query string (ex: vid=123) which calls the DB.

When I manually change the id in the location bar (ex: vid=125), the page refreshes all of the data pulled via the server scripts to reflect the contents of the new vid, but the UL still has the old content until you do a hard refresh, at which point the UL is populated with the correct values.

I've tried clearing the innerHTML before the UL is loaded, but no dice. The browser seems to be caching the dynamically loaded value of the UL even though the script isn't called until the dom is loaded.

```
$(o.uniqueName).innerHTML = '';
$(o.uniqueName).innerHTML = response.responseText;
```

Any idea what I could do to force this AJAX call to refresh when manually changing the query string? Linking to different pages via a link to that page works like a charm every time.

Comment: if u r using chrome, try add a breakpoint to DOM node to observe what's happening in that `ul`

Comment: open `developer tool`, in `elements` tab, right click on target node, select `break on` -> `subtree modification`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure enough, when I looked at the breakpoints I was able to find that on the reload of the page it was behaving differently because a long time ago someone coded it to do that. It was a matter of examining that behavior and changing the logic accordingly. Thanks!